# A word that would mean the following- "A desperate search for"

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, synonyms

I have tried googling and stuff but couldn't find any satisfactory suggestion that would mean "A desperate search for"

Comment: What about *pining*?

Comment: "Grope" would be a word for, eg, trying to find a flashlight in an auto's glove compartment when it's pitch black.

Answer (score 5):

The closest I can proffer is-

**rummage**

: to search for something especially by moving and looking through the contents  of   a place.

:  to engage in an undirected or haphazard search

- [ransack](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rummage)

**(**[MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rummage)**)**

==================================================================

v. - search haphazardly

- “We *rummaged* through the drawers”

n. - a search for something (often causing disorder or confusion)

- “he gave the attic a good *rummage* but couldn't find his skis”

**(**[vocabulary.com](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/rummage)**)**

Answer (score 3):

[Scour](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/scour)
"He scoured the countryside, desperate to find his dog."

verb (used with object) - to range over, as in a search:
     They scoured the countryside for the lost child.

verb (used without object) - to range about, as in search of something.

[ransack](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/ransack)
[ran-sak] 
verb (used with object)
1.to search thoroughly or vigorously through (a house, receptacle, etc.):
They ransacked the house for the missing letter.
2.to search through for plunder; pillage:
The enemy ransacked the entire town.

Comment: +1 for scour. most appropriate, though I personally find rummage quite evocative of desperation.